# Overlooking AttributeError exceptions in Python using VS Code debugger

Tags: python, pandas, exception, visual-studio-code, attributeerror

I have a massive loop that I am trying to debug in VS Code and running my python app in.

I keep hitting this AttributeError and it pauses the debugger which I DON'T want it to do. I want to bypass it and let it finish (which it does without debugger running).

The error:

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: )

I really don't want to hit F5 a billion times as I am trying to get to near the end of my program to see whatcertain variables in my Panda's DataFrame are. Is this possible?

Comment: where is this exception generated? Inside Pandas? Have you enabled the `Raised Breakpoint` check in the VSC Breakpoint View? Have you tried the `"justMyCode": true` property of the Python launch config

Comment: I will have to look into all of these. I want it to ignore those breakpoints and get to the rest of my code at the end. I might also just run the code without debugging and find a way to print my dataframe to see how it looks.